# How can I store EditText's changes in the items of a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, adapter, textwatcher

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter. Each row has an `EditText`. Each `EditText` has an initial value related to that row and user can change this value using `EditTexts`.

I want to store these changed values. I defined `TextWatcher` for each `EditText` but it does not work correctly especially when I scroll or filter data.

How can I do that?

Am I using a suitable approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was by `TextWatcher`. I solved it using  `OnKeyListener`:

```
private boolean programmaticalTextChange = false;

private KeyEvent UnknownKey = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN);

    public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher
    {
        private EditText editText;

        public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText)
        {
            this.editText = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (!programmaticalTextChange)
                editText.dispatchKeyEvent(UnknownKey);
        }
    }


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       //...
       myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                updateItem(item, v, rowView);
                return false;
            }
        });
        myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(myEditText));

}

protected void updateItem(MyClass item, View v) {
        try {
            item.Qty = Double.valueOf(((EditText) v).getText()
                    .toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```